# Django static files on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

There are a bunch of questions similar to this one, but after going through some of them, I still can't get it right.

I have a Django app and I want to serve static and media files using an AWS S3 Bucket. I can run `python manage.py collectstatic` and the files are added to the bucket. However, I am getting a 404 not found error for static files on the browser. There was a point in time that my configurations worked because I was able to see the files coming from s3 by inspecting the page, but I can't find what was changed for it not to work now.

Here's my settings.py:

```py
USES_S3 = os.getenv('USES_S3') == 'True'

if USES_S3:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=31536000'}
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'core/static'),
)
```

storages_backend.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
```

I also tried to set the following variables, with no success:

```py
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 'virtual'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-3'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
```

Any idea what could it be? I don't understand how collectstatic works and creates the files on the bucket but then I get 404.

Here's also an example of one of my html files (this one is the base.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE10 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://appseed.us/admin-dashboards/django-dashboard-dattaable">
    
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- fontawesome icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/fonts/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <!-- animation css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/plugins/animation/css/animate.min.css">
    <!-- vendor css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <link href="{% static 'ronfe.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

</head>

<body>

    <!-- [ Pre-loader ] start -->
    <div class="loader-bg">
        <div class="loader-track">
            <div class="loader-fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    {% include 'includes/navigation.html' %}

    <!-- SideBar -->
    {% include 'includes/sidebar.html' %}

    <div class="pcoded-main-container">
        <div class="pcoded-wrapper">

            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

        </div>
    </div>

    {% include 'includes/scripts.html' %}

    <!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your HTML

Comment: command collectstatic transfers your files to a static folder (in your case AWS S3) that means you managed to configurate it correctly :)  Problem must me on your amazon configuration or in your html

Comment: @bazzuk123 thank you for your response. I've updated my question with my base.html

Comment: you should load every static file with {% static 'path/name.css' %}

Comment: if you goes to your bucket file url (eg. YOUR-BUCKET-NAME-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static/assets/plugins/animation/css/animate.min.css ) do you see 404 page or is it loading correctly?

Comment: Where you do `/static/assets/fonts/...` you should likely be doing `{% static "assets/fonts/..." %}`

Comment: @bazzuk123 http://bucketname.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/static/assets/plugins/animation/css/animate.min.css loads correctly

Comment: I've changed to {% static "..." %} but I am getting "400 Attempted access to '...' denied." @bazzuk123

Comment: I've changed to {% static "..." %} but I am getting "400 Attempted access to '...' denied." @markwalker_

Comment: Ok, I got it. Silly mistake. It must be {% static "..." %} but the path must not contain "/static" 
Thank for your help! @bazzuk123

Comment: Ok, I got it. Silly mistake. It must be {% static "..." %} but the path must not contain "/static" 
Thank for your help! @markwalker_